# Do you get extra trains for ending the game?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, end-game

In Ticket To Ride, A player triggers the end of the game can do so with 0 trains in their supply. Do they then get to use the extra trains from the box to take their final turn?

Comment: No, Each player can only use the 45 train cars in their supply. If you have no train cars left on your last turn, then you can't claim a route that turn. [ticket-to-ride]

Comment: This sounds a bit like a rule someone teaching the game has made up to give them an advantage.  As said already the rules are clear on how many trains a player has in each version.

Comment: Genuine question: which line in the rules made you think this was an option?

Comment: @PhilipKendall I think the real question is: what line in the rules answers this question?

Comment: It should be emphasized that different versions and maps of the game may have players use different quantities of trains.  For example the [UK map](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/182078/ticket-ride-map-collection-volume-5-united-kingdom) has players use only 35 trains each.  Most use 45, but it is always worth confirming during setup.

Answer (score 7):

No. Each player can only use trains of their own color, and there should be none of that color in the box (except colors which aren't used because there are less than the maximum number of players).

Comment: Many of the versions I have had a few spare trains of each colour included in the box but you are correct in your answer.

Comment: Ah, those are called spare parts for a reason :)

Comment: I now feel obligated to go and count all the trains in my copy...

Comment: @PhilipKendall, just wait until the next game when you meticulously arrange them nicely in three groups of 3x5 trains at the start. Makes any extras or missing ones evident. Isn't that what everyone else also does, right? Right?? :)

Comment: Specifically, the rules mention during setup that each player takes 45 train cars in their color. Those are the only pieces available for the player to use. The rules also mention that there are 45 train cars of each color packaged in the box, plus a few extra *replacements* in each color.